# BeautifulSoup import error in Python3.3

Tags: python, windows, beautifulsoup

Only a week into Python. I've installed BeautifulSoup4 using easy_install. Install seems to be okay being that no error when in Python shell and use from bs4 import BeautifulSoup.

Error comes up when trying to use "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" in a script that I call from cmd console on win7 "python C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\precipitation.py"

> > > from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
#precipitation.py:

import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KYIP/2013/6/16/DailyHistory.html6")
#htmltext = htmlfile.read()
#regex = b'<td class="indent"><span>Precipitation</span></td>\n<td><span class="nobr"><span class="b">(.+?)</span>''
#pattern = re.compile(regex)

print('Who made the Soup?!')
```

Error when running script:
python C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\precipitation.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\precipitation.py", line 3, in
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
File "C:\Users\Ryan\Desktop\precipitation.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: cannot import name BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Is it the exact error message you get? Are you sure you don't have file `bs4.py` on your desktop? (Appart from one filename, your error looks like something you would get with a file `bs4` on your desktop)

Comment: Right on. I created a file bs4.py on the desktop to mess with BS. That's why it was working earlier. ;-) Thanks for pointing that out. Could you explain how/why that happens?

Comment: can you check python module documents if it everything is correct and you shoul try to install again with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install python3.5+ at least. Python3.3 was released in 2013 (7 years ago!).

It seems you are running on windows. In this case, you might just download anaconda that will make your life much easier for you: https://anaconda.org/anaconda/beautifulsoup4.

References:

- https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup